# Userform to open when sheet opens

Tags: vba, excel

A little stuck with VBA, im trying to get my userform "ParcelDataEntry" to open when i select a sheet from my combo box which i have on my front page which will have various other options when i cross this hurdle.

All 54 worksheets have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    ParcelDataEntry.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: The dropdown is irrelevant, as is the fact the the combobox links to other sheets. You need to handle a worksheet event that fires everytime anything changes on that sheet, verify that the modified cell is the one you're after, and then bring up your form. You need to be more specific about where exactly it is that you're stumped, and show us what you've got so far / what you've tried. Cheers!

Comment: Do you have some code to show where you stand? What aspect of the process are you confused about? Is the combo box an ActiveX control or a Form control? Is your Front page a worksheet or a form?

Comment: Ok sorry kind of new to VBA.

So i have this code in all 54 sheets

Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    ParcelDataEntry.Show
End Sub

Comment: The combo box is form control, this works fine it opens the sheet i select on there. But when i select the sheet i need it doesnt open my userform. My front sheet is just to have access to combo box and other things which i will add later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a Worksheet_Open event. Instead use the Workbook_SheetActivate event. You should place this code in the ThisWorkbook code module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call OpenDataEntryForm
End Sub
```

Treat your userform like an object and declare and instantiate it accordingly.

```
Public Sub OpenDataEntryForm()

Dim dataEntryForm As ParcelDataEntry

' Create an instance of the form
Set dataEntryForm = New ParcelDataEntry
' Show the form
dataEntryForm.Show
' Do something here

' If the form was opened as Modal, then the code here will only run
' once the form has been hidden/closed
' Now destroy the object
Set dataEntryForm = Nothing

End Sub
```